# CSS3 transition properties; getting error

Tags: css

Am trying to set transition on three properties, but keep on getting error that I have not set it on all of the transition properties. (Do not want delay, so have left that out.)

What's missing?

```
a {
  color: #c44743;
  transition: color 1s ease;
}

a:hover {
  color: #d56d68;
}
```

Comment: [Your code works just fine](http://jsfiddle.net/qaev7j4k/), the original color is just very similar to the hovered state. Please recreate the situation and describe exactly what's going wrong

Comment: OOPS! I didn't see your comment until after I answered lol :) +1

Answer (score -1):

Your code syntax is perfectly fine.  Change the colors so they are not as similar :)